# What does the content of the page table look like after a page has been swapped out to the disk?

Tags: memory, operating-systems, virtual-memory, memory-management, paging

From what I understand, the page table maps virtual addresses to physical addresses. But what if a page has been swapped out to the disk? 
Wouldn't the location of the data take more bits to write down than the physical address? Doesn't the location of the data change when the swap file is modified?
Is this problem solved in different ways in different operating systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the easier question first:

> Doesn't the location of the data change when the swap file is modified?

There is no modification of the pagefile that causes the location of existing data in it to change. If a pagefile is extended, more clusters (grouped in "extents" or "runs") are simply added to its end, so the location of existing data doesn't change. Pagefile locations are always relative to the start of a pagefile, so even if the already-existing extents were somehow moved, the pagefile locations wouldn't change.

Now, about the bits:

> Wouldn't the location of the data take more bits to write down than the physical address ?

Yes, if the pagefile can be larger than the possible physical memory size, you would need more bits to specify a page within the pagefile than bits to specify a physical page number.

In x86 without PAE enabled there are 20 bits in the page table entry (PTE) for the physical page number (PFN, short for "page frame number"). (PTEs are 32 bits. The other 12 are flag bits, bit 0 being the "valid" or "page present" bit that says you won't get a page fault when you reference the page. Three of the flag bits are reserved for use by the OS. Others have meanings like "read-only", "only accessible in kernel mode", "cache disable", etc.) (Everything in this paragraph is determined by the CPU architecture - it is independent of OS.)

In Windows the same bits in the PTE that hold the PFN for a valid page are, for a page that's in the pagefile, indeed used to hold the location-within-pagefile. This is expressed as an offset, in page-sized units, from the start of the pagefile. This does limit pagefiles to 4 GB, just as the 20-bit PFN for physical pages limits RAM to 4 GB on these systems.

However, you can have multiple pagefiles. There are four more bits in the PTE which, for a page in a pagefile, indicate the pagefile number. Thus there can be 16 pagefiles, for a total of 64 GB possible pagefile space.

When you enable PAE on the older x86-only processors the PTEs become 64 bits wide, and the CPU implements 24 bits (up from 20) of PFN in the PTE. This allows 64 GB of RAM, and in Windows, 64 GB pagefiles. There are a lot of unused bits in that PTE format, so an OS could actually support larger pagefiles; I'm not sure if 32-bit Windows does.

On the newer 64-bit processors in 64-bit mode there are 40 bits of PFN and, again, the same bits are used to hold the pagefile offset for invalid (i.e. not-present) pages. So, RAM or pagefile, we can describe 2^40 pages - that's one "binary trillion" of pages, 1024 to the 4th. And each page is 4 KiB. Hence a 4 PiB pagefile is the max, and also the maximum RAM supported by the hardware. And again, Windows says you can have multiple pagefiles. I don't think we'll be running into pagefile space limits anytime soon. :)

All of the above that is not enforced by the CPU is OS-specific. There is actually no reason that the location-within-pagefile has to be stored in the PTE at all; another structure could be used. On processors like PowerPC that use a hashed page table the OS *can't* store it in the PTE, since an invalid PTE isn't stored at all in the HPT structure.

But on x86/x64 there is really no reason to not use the invalid PTE. This works, by the way, because when the "valid" bit is clear, the MMU doesn't care one bit (pun intended) about the rest of the PTE. So for invalid PTEs, all but one bit are available for the OS to use as it likes. In Windows in fact there are several other forms of "invalid PTE", depending on the state of the page. For a page on the standby or modified list, for example, the PFN field still contains the page's physical location in RAM. A PTE for an invalid page might refer to a "virtual address descriptor", or if it's a shared page, to a "prototype PTE". The hardware MMU never sees either of those structures, only PTEs.

Full details are in the "Memory Management" chapter of *Windows Internals* by Solomon, Russinovich, and Ionescu.

Comment: Thank you for the good feedback! If you have any followup Qs, don't hesitate to post them as comments, or modify your original Q.